# Puppet - Puppet master questionable behavior in pulling relevant config from the correct node

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I'm new to puppet and I've setup two puppet master instances which are in same IP range. 
Eg : Assume there are A and B puppet master nodes. A = 192.168.4.23 and B = 192.168.4.66. There are puppet agents configured to to pull from each respective node. Lets say C pulls from A and D pulls from B.

My configuration where C pulls from A is fine, thats what I expect. But when D pulls from B it doesn't work. But when I replace a file that D pulls from B, with a file in A placed in B then the agent script runs properly.

Appreciate any idea on what might be going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a thoroughly confusing question...

```
A.fileA <-> C Works.
B.fileB <-> D Does not work.
B.fileA <-> D Works.
```

There's just not enough information to go off of here.

- What is fileA?
- What is fileB?
- What is the script?
- What is the relationship between A and B where a a fileA is given to B?

Without this information, I might only offer a recommendation. Assuming you're using some source control management for your manifests and modules, if you're not already using r10k/code manager with dynamic directory environments, you should look into that in order to improve the integrity of the data available to the agents on each of the masters. This way, you can be relatively certain that what you expect to be on each of the masters truly is.